# grabbing values from f.select options_for_select in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Hi in my apps I have a scaffold, were users can select different type of paper and add a paper weight for each type. Then I calculate the running total of paper_weight for each user in the ApplicationController.

I want to be more specific and show the users the average weight of each paper_type they are using.  I´m a bit lost since I ´m rather new to rails, can anyone here help me??

thanks in advance

below are my views.

in paper/new.html.erb

```
<div class="control-group"> 
    <%= f.label :paper_type, class: 'control-label' %><br>
        <div class="controls">
            <%= f.select(:paper_type, options_for_select([['Skrifstofupappír', 'Skrifstofupappír'], ['Dagblaðapappír', 'Dagblaðapappír'], ['Glans_&_tímaritapappír', 'Glans_&_tímaritapappír'], ['Annað', 'Annað']])) %>
      </div>
</div>  


<div class="control-group"> 
    <%= f.label :paper_weight, class: 'control-label' %><br>
        <div class="controls">
            <%= f.number_field :paper_weight %>
        </div>
</div>
```

in ApplicationController.rb

```
@paper_weight_per_capita = current_user.papers.sum(:paper_weight) / (current_user.profile.staff)
```

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you're asking. Do you want to display the `@paper_weight_per_capita` somewhere?

Comment: Sorry for the unclear question @JamesKlein :) . I´m trying to find out how I can display the average weight for each paper_type in the f.select. So in the view I´m able to how much the 'Skrifstofupappír', 'Dagblaðapappír' etc weights.  My problem is basically in how I can grab those values and display them separately.

Comment: Gotcha. Where do these names exist? Here they are hard-coded into the view but are these in fact names of `PaperType` records in your database that also have an `average_weight` attribute on them? If not, do you want to hard-code the average weights as well?

Comment: thanks for quick response @James Klein...If the user select for example 'Dagblaðapappír' in the f. select and then puts in a weight it looks like this in the database: #<Paper id: 1, paper_type: "Dagblaðapappír", paper_weight: #<BigDecimal:7ff54f8396f8,'0.1E3',9(18)>  The user can add as many instances of different paper_types as he wants. Then I want to be able to show the user in a running total how many Kg the user have for each paper_type. So I need a way to grab the paper_type in this bit current_user.papers.sum(:paper_weight) but not only the the paper_weight as it is now...

Comment: Oh okay. So you don't actually want any changes to the form code that you posted, you instead want a view such as `user/show.html.erb` that has a table inside of it with all the papers, correct?

Comment: Yes, exactly, exept I want to post it on the index page as running total, like I'm doing with the paper_weight, but instead of showing only the average weight for paper I want the running total to show the running total for each paper_type. Do you know a way to do that?

Comment: Yes I do. Final question before answering this, which index page do you want this on? `users/index` or `papers/index`?

Comment: Ohhh I´m so grateful , it would be awesome.  Actually I´ll be probably be using it on a partial called _average_user_total.html.erb. to begin with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First a tweak.

In your `Paper` class is where you want to put the array of acceptable values for the paper type. That way you can validate input from perhaps more than just this form in the future. It also allows you to test that code plus putting an array right in the view like that is just not the best practice.

```
class Paper
  PAPER_TYPES = ['Skrifstofupappír', 'Dagblaðapappír', 'Glans_&_tímaritapappír', 'Annað']
  ...
```

Then in your view, change to this.

```
<%= f.select(:paper_type, options_for_select(Paper::PAPER_TYPES)) %>
```

That doesn't answer your question, just a tweak to make your code cleaner and testable.

Then in your `User` model

```
def average_paper_types
  self.papers.group(:paper_type).sum(:paper_weight)
end
```

And in your partial:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <% current_user.average_paper_types.each do |pair| %>
        <th><%= pair[0] %></th>
      <% end %>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <% current_user.average_paper_types.each do |pair| %>
        <td><%= pair[1] %></td>
      <% end %>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: you don't need to do this: PAPER_TYPES = [['Skrifstofupappír', 'Skrifstofupappír'], ['Dagblaðapappír', 'Dagblaðapappír'], ['Glans_&_tímaritapappír', 'Glans_&_tímaritapappír'], ['Annað', 'Annað']]

the reason for doing the two dimensional would be because there are different values. for instance, you want to show the user a string but save an id. Like this SODAS = [['Coke', 1], ['Pepsi', 2]]. When just dealing with the string you can just say SODAS = ['Coke', 'Pepsi'] and it will work exactly the same as if you listed them twice in a 2 dimensional array.

Comment: Thank you so much @James Klein this works like a charm and I understand what I´m doing, great guidance and professional approach... Thumbs up mate!!!

Comment: I changed the PAPER_TYPES to on line of each string, it works also that way....Thank you both

Comment: @karma_police, absolutely. I just wanted to mention the refactor but hadn't looked at the array itself. Glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

Not positive I understand correctly, but I think what you're trying to do (based on comments) is display the averages of each individual paper type on the index page.

As you're iterating through the different types of paper that belong to the user, you could call a method that performs that calculation. Inside that method you might do something like this:

```
def paper_weight_by_type(user_id, paper_type)
  u = User.find(user_id)
  weight_by_type = Paper.where(user_id: user_id, paper_type: paper_type).pluck(:paper_weight)
  # then return this
  weight_by_type.inject(:+)      
end
```

this is a crude version. This could be an instance method on either user or paper in which case you wouldn't need both arguments. (ie current_user.paper_weight_by_type(paper_type) ...could also make it a class method and just pass both arguments by adding self. in front of def) Also several ways you could probably cut down on the number of queries being run...but this would get the job done. You'd want to call it from the paper loop on the index page however you ended up doing it. I would get it working one way and then improve it from there. Hope this helps.