# Saving running total to database every other week or so, in rails?

Tags: ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-4, graph

I am building this app were the users are able to add to the database how many km they are driving, how many kg of paper they are using etc. Then the average fro each category for all users is displayed on the index page. I do that with code like this in the application controller.

```
@all_users_transp_km_sum = Transport.average(:transport_km)
```

But I was thinking about it would be cool to show the values for the running totals in a graph on the index page. So I was thinking if I could somehow grab the values for each running total once a week or so. Then the graph would show values once a week.

Is that possible? advise or guidance would be much appreciated

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to keep track of all averages once a week and display those weekly averages on a graph?  If that's the case that is quite simple.  First you'll need a table to store each average record taken.  Then you can use graphs like "chart.js" and plot it.  If you clarify exactly what you want I can give a more specific suggestion.

Comment: Hi @bkunzi01 , Yes thats basically what I´m asking about, you understood correctly :)  can you give me a hint how to do this, I understand I have to make a table for the record taken, but what confuses me is how I can grab the records, for example every monday?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Heroku, you could use something like the Heroku Scheduler to run a custom rake task that updates the data to be shown every Monday. You'd put this code in lib/tasks and name your file something like every_monday.rake

Inside that file you would say something like:

```
task :scheduler_every_monday => :environment do
  # update stuff
end
```

Then you'd go to heroku and open up the add-on for scheduler and drop in the task. Have it update the model that's being used for the chart. For the charts themselves, check out: http://chartkick.com/

Comment: thanks for the answer @karma_police I´m not using heroku at the moment as in I haven´t deployed to it. Is this the only way or?

Comment: No. There are other ways. You could use a cron job to update the data weekly. Check out something like the whenever gem or clockwork (or any cron job, really).

Comment: you're welcome. here are links: https://github.com/tomykaira/clockwork https://github.com/javan/whenever

Comment: thank you so much @karma_police.... if you are on fire today you are welcome to take a look at another question I´ve been struggling with :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35615362/grabbing-values-from-f-select-options-for-select-in-rails-app